# Finding missing text or code in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Is it possible to find which pages in Dreamweaver are missing a certain snippet of code or text?

I have a site with hundreds of pages, and I would like to search for the pages that are missing a certain snippet of code.

I'm open to using a different software if Dreamweaver cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver can find the missing snippet , first you need to `one` page in Dreamweaver , and then press `ctrl+f` (find) and change `current document` to `folder` and browser your folder path, then copy paste what you need to search and click `replace all` then you need to open the folder and check the missing `html` ain't modified, other's are modified new date ,you can see which pages are missing the snippet,

Comment: While this is the better answer from the two, it's still not an effective way to accomplish this.  It would take a long time for a website with hundreds or thousands of pages.  Too bad DW does not have this function.

Comment: i hope you understand my answer, if its use full to you don't forgot tick the answer